# Trying to change backgroundColor every x seconds

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, uicolor

What i am trying to do is change the backgroundColor of my screen to a new color every 5 seconds but i keep getting two errors. One is in the extension of UIColor, where it says "Declaration is only valid at file scope" and in the self.view.backgroundColor where it says that "Type 'UIColor' has no member of 'randomColor'". Thank you or your help and time and I ope it helps some other people out there. Below is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var person: UIView!

    extension UIColor {
        func randomColor() -> UIColor{
            let red = CGFloat(drand48())
            let green = CGFloat(drand48())
            let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
            return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
    func changeBackround() -> UIColor {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.viewDidLoad()

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: Selector("changeBackground"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Your `changeBackround` function isn't returning anything, even though it's defined as returning a `UIColor` (and it's misspelled)... Not sure if you intended for it to return something or not.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare class extension within the declaration scope of another class. You should move the block

```
extension UIColor {
    func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Outside of the scope of `class ViewController: UIViewController`.

Plus, here `func randomColor() -> UIColor` declares a method on instances of `UIColor`. You want to declare this func as static to have a class method. The resulting file should be

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var person: UIView!

    func changeBackround() -> UIColor {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.randomColor()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.viewDidLoad()

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: Selector("changeBackground"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

}

extension UIColor {
    static func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason for this could be because I took out the -> UIColor return type in the function changeBackground() but other than this I do not know why or how this could happen. The code builds successfully but once my simulator loads Xcode pops back up on the appDelegate file with the class heading highlighted in red. So, I guess there is a bug. This means it is not the code's fault and my code is correct, but how do I solve this or debug.